# Variable selection with restricted cubic splines

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, multivariate-regression

Is there any function in R for doing variable selection (backward elimination) in a multiple logistic regression using restricted cubic splines like **mvrs** procedure for STATA?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for a definition of restricted cubic splines?